# Is there a reason to use constructors over static methods? (Future.delayed, DateTime.now)

Tags: dart

Coming from a C# background, I find myself often writing code like:

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var delay = Future.delayed(...);
```

This code doesn't work (`NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Symbol("now")'`), I'm missing the word `new` because these are constructors. I keep doing this over and over, and every time I read the error, I'm confused for a minute before I realise I did it again!

It makes me curious; is there some advantage to using constructors like this over static methods, or is it just a convention because Dart has named constructors?

Are there any guidelines on this; should we use named constructors in all of our own code where we would normally have a static method that returns an instance?

Comment: Does dart have `static` methods?  Note that the Dart documentation has some guidance about this here: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#members and here: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#types

Comment: Apparently so; found the same link just now! :)

Comment: No worries, you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 4):

Found [this](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#do-use-constructors-instead-of-static-methods-to-create-instances) in the [Dart Style Guide](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/)

### DO use constructors instead of static methods to create instances.

Constructors are invoked using new or const which communicates clearly at the callsite that an object is being created. Named constructors and factory constructors in Dart give you all of the flexibility of static methods in other languages, while still allowing the callsite to appear like a regular constructor invocation.

```dart
// GOOD
class Point {
  num x, y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
  Point.zero()
      : x = 0,
        y = 0;
}

// BAD
class Point {
  num x, y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
  static Point zero() => new Point(0, 0);
}
```

### Update: Drawbacks of named constructors

Just discovered, you can't pass constructors to functions (eg. as functions). Having to change my named constructors to static methods! :(

Comment: There are many in favor of making `new` optional http://dartbug.com/20750. Mostly the distinction it is an annoyance because you have to check if it is a method or a constructor to know if you have to use `new` or not.

Comment: The other side of the issue is that if the guidelines are followed, you know you're always going to use `new` when you want an instance of a class, and you're never going to use `new` if you're not asking for an instance of a class.  That is to say, the annoyance of having to check whether it's a method or a constructor exists because someone wrote methods that return instances instead of constructors (factory or otherwise).

Comment: Just discovered, you can't pass constructors to functions (eg. as functions). Having to change my named constructors to static methods! :(

Comment: Just run into this as well. I've opened a feature request for being able to use constructors as functions (as the language somehow suggest them to be) https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35901.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use generic type arguments you need to use a constructor. A function doesn't allow to pass generic type arguments, a constructor does.

Comment: Kinda sucks that some things require constructor (this) and some require static function (passing it to another function) :(